# Unable to generate PDF with neural network graph

Tags: r, plot, neural-network

I'm trying to create a hard-copy image of a neural network graph and it keeps failing. If I try to create a PNG, nothing is generated, and if I try to generate a PDF I get a small file output that refuses to open with "file may be damaged" errors. If I just let it display in a graphics window, the image comes up fine.

I'm using 2.15.1 on OS X (10.7.4), built by Macports. The code I'm working with at the moment:

```
library(ALL)
library(neuralnet)
data(ALL)

ALL.pdat <- pData(ALL)
bt <- factor(substring(ALL.pdat$BT,1,1))
all.sds <- apply(exprs(ALL),1,sd)
top.10.sds <- rank(all.sds)>length(all.sds)-10
exprs.top.10 <- as.data.frame(t(exprs(ALL)[top.10.sds,]))
nn.data <- cbind(exprs.top.10, as.numeric(bt))
##  Gene names start with a number, and that causes problems when trying to set up the
##  formula for neuralnet.
col.names <- paste("g", colnames(nn.data), sep = '')
col.names[11] <- "bt"
colnames(nn.data) <- col.names
my.nn <- neuralnet(bt ~ g36108_at + g36638_at + g37006_at + g38096_f_at + g38319_at + g38355_at + g38514_at + g38585_at + g39318_at + g41214_at, nn.data,  hidden = 10, threshold = 0.01)
summary(my.nn)
pdf("./nn-all.pdf")
plot.nn(my.nn)
dev.off()
png("./nn-all.png")
plot.nn(my.nn)
dev.off()
```

I've even rebooted the machine to make sure that all the memory is cleared up, and that didn't help any.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having problems saving a neural net plot using neuralnet package - R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866740/having-problems-saving-a-neural-net-plot-using-neuralnet-package-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple reproducible example:

```
pdf("test.pdf")
 set.seed(42)
 plot(runif(20),rnorm(20))
 png("test.png")
  set.seed(42)
  plot(runif(20),rnorm(20))
 dev.off()
```

If I try to open the PDF with Adobe Reader on my German Windows 7, I get a nice informative error message telling me that the file cannot be opened because the file is in use by another application. This can be fixed easily:

```
pdf("test.pdf")
 set.seed(42)
 plot(runif(20),rnorm(20))
dev.off() #make sure to close the graphics device
png("test.png")
 set.seed(42)
 plot(runif(20),rnorm(20))
dev.off()
```

## Edit:

The problem is `plot.nn`. Until the package gets patched, you need to redefine `plot.nn` manually as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11881985/1412059).

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem. The error I get trying to open the PDF file is "It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize." No PNG file gets generated.

Comment: For the record, I can run your example code, and the PNG and PDF plots do get generated correctly.

Comment: I have no access to package ALL, but if I use the expample from `?plot.nn` I cannot reproduce the error. What is the output of `dev.off()`when you run your code?

Comment: So, running the same code of mine on Linux (RHEL5u4, 2.15.0) gives the same problem -- PDF file that won't open (though with a bit more info about what is wrong from xpdf), no PNG file generated.